# Compile Linq Expression using Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, linq-expressions

Is there a way to compile the following string in C#
`string linqExpression = "(seq) => seq.Average()"` using roslyn?

Instead of doing this:

```
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@" using System; 
    using System.Linq; 
    public class RoslynLinq 
    { 
        public void Execute(int[] a) 
        { 
            Func<int[], double> func = (seq) => seq.Average(); 
            Console.WriteLine(func(a)); 
        } 
    }");
```

Can I do:

```
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("Func<int[], double> func = (seq) => seq.Select((x)=>x).Average()");
```

Comment: Yes, the same way you compile any other expression.

Comment: What I meant was that, instead of doing this:
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using System; 
using System.Linq;                                                                 
                                                                 
public class RoslynLinq 
{ 
public void Execute(int[] a) 
{ 
Func<int[], double> func = (seq) => seq.Average();
Console.WriteLine(func(a));
} 
}");

Can I do:

SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(“Func<int[], double> func = (seq) => seq.Select((x)=>x).Average()”);

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're actually asking whether you can parse a statement without a containing function or class.

Just pass [`SourceCodeKind.Script`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SourceCodeKind.cs,23) and that will work fine.

Comment: There is also [`SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs,41bba2b7f36dcf28)